# SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression - How to do in Python 2

Tags: python, pyspark

My Python version is 2.7 and I am using this code:

```
 df1.select(*[x for x in df1.columns if x!='fields'], F.col("fields.*")).show()
```

But I got this error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-16-3d81a8b987ed>", line 1
    df1.select(*[x for x in df1.columns if x!='fields'], F.col("fields.*")).show()
SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression
```

How can I modify my code to make it work in Python 2? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try appending your select expression to list comprehension.

```
expr = [x for x in df1.columns if x!='fields']+[F.col("fields.*")]
df1.select(*expr).show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try by passing **`col`** on both of your expressions in `.select`

```
df1.select(*[F.col(x) for x in df1.columns if x!='fields'], F.col("fields.*")).show()

#or without col in .select

df.select("fields.*",*[x for x in df.columns if x !='fields']).show()
```